# I need open a service when i close the application

Tags: android

Why it not possible ?

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), notificationService.class));
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

I really need to execute a service when the application isn't running.

Comment: What exact issue you are facing? And what result should be accomplished?

Comment: Please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: Simply nothing happens